# This question doesn't meet our standards and is an excellent candidate for deletion

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-questions

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14588/which-path-would-be-better-in-the-long-run

This question doesn't meet our standards and is an excellent candidate for deletion.

> "Questions seeking advice on what job to take, what skills to learn, etc. are off-topic as the answers are rarely useful to anyone else."